# How do I efficiently search for ICs?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, research

I am a computer engineering student with an electronics background (i.e. mandatory circuit design and analog electronic courses) and my degree thesis requires me to design an electronics project.

So now I have this project to get done and of course I have to look for ICs that do this and that. Do I just Google stuff until I find what I need? I feel really lost since my electronics background is just that, a background, so I know how diodes, opamps and transistors work but I have no idea what the various acronyms (like PHY, MIPI, TTL and so on) mean, so what usually happens is I Google "integrated *feature 1* *feature 2* ", then I click on any results that look related, read datasheets (when I can find them, since many are under NDA), stop to Google any acronym I don't know, which usually gets me to know what it means but not how it works, rinse and repeat.

Some of the time I can actually find what I want, but most of the time I just spend a whole day staring at my screen feeling completely lost and at the end of the day I turn off my computer feeling like I haven't accomplished anything. Most components look like they are not interoperable, have different standards for input and output or actually have the same standards but call them by different names because of copyright!

So my question is: **how do I efficiently search for the ICs I need?** My project doesn't sound so hard on paper, I have a very good idea of *what* I have to do but I have a hard time finding the components I need. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Try using searching components destributer's websites like digikey

Comment: ... or Mouser, Newark/Farnell, RS components, etc

Comment: If you don't know the difference between PHY and TTL, then the search problem has been reduced to you first getting more informed. Gather up terms, read as quickly as possible to get ideas of general categories and quickly eliminate those that make no sense. You've got some fast learning to do. Give yourself the time required for this. Always pull "unknowns" to the front of the project. This means your ignorance as much as it means solutions to new unsolved problems.

Comment: find a local "measurement" or "instrumentation" company, or "consultancy"; call and ask to have lunch with a senior person; your local power utility company can help you with suggestions of people to chat with. And read old issues of EDN or Wireless World or Popular Electronics or RadioElectronics. Learn to solder, and build a discrete one-transistor amplifier, using a small loudspeaker for both the input and output. Common Emitter is useful configuration for that.

Comment: Break your project into smaller parts - individual tasks needed to accomplish the complete project.  Find how other people have solved those smaller tasks.  Those solutions will show you things you need to know.  Combine the requirements of the smaller tasks to the requirements of your project.  In combining them, you will often find you can simplify things.

Comment: Block diagrams are often a good way to attack a larger project.  Sketch a diagram of how you think it should work.  Learn about each of your blocks, decide on a solution.  This will often cause you to rearrange your block diagram.  Redraw, learn about the next block.  Repeat.

Comment: Yoou may find the engineering glossary at Maxim integrated useful: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/glossary/index.mvp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summary: It's an incremental process, not a "big bang", to go from college theory work to a substantial project. There is no substitute for experience.

---

After reading the whole question, I don't *think* your real question is the title of "Where and how do I search for ICs?". Instead I think your real question is more like - how can you choose components for a project, when you don't understand what components you need, and you don't understand enough of the datasheets to be confident that you are choosing suitable components.

> I am a computer engineering student and started being interested in electronics for my degree thesis.

You don't say how much electronics is taught in your computer engineering course. However even though you are interested in electronics, if they aren't teaching you enough electronics for what you want to do in your thesis, then don't try to make this an electronics thesis. Instead, keep electronics as a hobby interest for now and focus on what you *can* do for your thesis.

As already mentioned in comments, you should consider approaches like block diagrams. That is similar to [decomposition in computer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_(computer_science)), where you break down a system requirement into functions, data types etc.

But what if you don't know enough about which electronic components are currently available, to know what blocks in your block diagram are sensible?

You said that you...

> feel that what I'm missing is a primer on...*the real world* or something.

Many (most?) of us went from theory to "real world" in steps by doing projects, starting with something small and getting bigger each time. I doubt that anyone went straight from theory to a (successful) big project. That experience, of making increasingly complex projects, does a few things (just like learning any new skill):

- You increase your *confidence* for tackling more complex projects, because of each previous success.
- You get to expand your *knowledge* of current technology with each new project. Each time you can focus on learning only what is new & different in *that* project, relying on your experience from *previous* projects for elements that are common between those projects and the new project.

  This increasing knowledge helps you to know what sensible "blocks" you can include on your next project block diagram. For example, at the beginning, you might not know how to detect when a voltage is above an upper limit or below a lower limit. For that project, you do some research and find there's a term for that — [window comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_detector) — and you can add that to the list of blocks which you can include in *future* block diagrams.

  Another important way to increase your knowledge incrementally is to read *project-based* books or magazines (Elektor is a current example of such a magazine - there were many others in the past, which have now disappeared) and build at least some of the projects. With each project you will learn new things, including new "blocks" (ICs, interfaces, functionality like window comparators etc.) for your future block diagrams.

A few final points, from my own experience:

- Sometimes you need to allow yourself to fail, at least initially, because that is when you are likely to learn the most.

  If you always do the same project type (e.g. flashing LEDs) then you will eventually be able to do them in your sleep, but you won't learn anything new. If you try something requiring different knowledge (e.g. designing a switch-mode power supply) it is more likely not to work first time. You'll learn lots from troubleshooting and fixing it, but that will take time - so don't choose a "stretch goal" project requiring new knowledge, with a hard deadline.
- One example of a book which is somewhere between the "circuit design" books you already found and real world knowledge, is ["Practical Electronics for Inventors" by Paul Scherz and Simon Monk](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Practical-Electronics-Inventors-Fourth-Scherz-ebook/dp/B01D5LXUYI). Early editions had several mistakes, and even the current latest (4th) edition has errata - but at least errata lists are available. Another example is ["Practical Electronics Handbook" by Ian Sinclair and John Dutton](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Practical-Electronics-Handbook-Ian-Sinclair/dp/0750680717). These books contain examples of the circuit design "building blocks" which you might find useful. You might prefer the style and contents of one book over another, so these are not specific recommendations, just examples of the type of book you might find useful.
- There is always ["The Art of Electronics" by Paul Horowitz and Winfield Hill](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Art-Electronics-Paul-Horowitz/dp/0521809266). However that is heavy on theory. So while it does include some practical information, if you haven't already read this book, check to see if it is "practical enough" for you.

  However, books on their own aren't enough. You have to try some projects, to find either "that was much easier than expected, so I can try something harder next time", or "oops, that is much harder than expected, I'll pick something simpler to build up my knowledge from a lower starting point".

In short: It's an incremental process, not a "big bang", to go from college theory work to a substantial project.

Comment: Thank you! You were very thorough and informative.
I did not jump into electronics from zero - I have mandatory circuit design and analog electronics courses in college and this thesis was proposed to me by a professor. 
I'll have a look at the books you mentioned - theory doesn't scare me, I'm used to that from college. And I'll also look into easier projects - although this thesis doesn't sound so hard on paper - since I do have a Raspberry Pi that is sitting there, just being used as a media center...thanks again!

Answer (score 9):

To be honest, you're asking 'How do I understand a massive subject quickly so I can design a project' and the answer is 'you can't', as you probably gathered. Your best path is to contact an experienced electronics engineer who can work with you on what you're trying to do.

As a start, search/look for demonstration boards that may be similar to your application you're designing. Bear in mind that will just give you examples of what you're trying to do, not the knowledge to reliably do it yourself.

But to go from zero to connecting and using something like a PHY reliably isn't something you'll discover from the relatively short amount of browsing time that a thesis makes available.